# Assigning date sequences to pandas groupby groups

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas with shops and item ids columns. I'd like to assign to each couple (shop, item_id) a data range of a month. for example if shop is called 'Toy' and item_id 'ball', I have something like this:

```
  shop item_id
0  Toy    ball
1  Toy    book
```

And I'd like to have something like this:

```
  shop item_id      date
0  Toy    ball  1-1-2015
1  Toy    ball  1-2-2015
2  Toy    ball  1-3-2015
3  Toy    ball  1-4-2015
4  Toy    book  1-1-2015
5  Toy    book  1-2-2015
6  Toy    book  1-3-2015
7  Toy    book  1-4-2015
```

How can I achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
df    
  shop item_id
0  Toy    ball
1  Toy    book
```

And

```
n = 5 # Number of days.
```

Start by repeating each of the DataFrame rows by the number of days.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(n, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```

Now, let's use `groupby`, `cumcount` and some timedelta arithmetic with `pd.DateOffset`:

```
days = pd.Series([
    pd.DateOffset(days=x) for x in df.groupby(['shop', 'item_id']).cumcount()
])
df['date'] = days + pd.to_datetime('2015-1-1')
print(df)

  shop item_id       date
0  Toy    ball 2015-01-01
1  Toy    ball 2015-01-02
2  Toy    ball 2015-01-03
3  Toy    ball 2015-01-04
4  Toy    ball 2015-01-05
5  Toy    book 2015-01-01
6  Toy    book 2015-01-02
7  Toy    book 2015-01-03
8  Toy    book 2015-01-04
9  Toy    book 2015-01-05
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I was looking for. You're awesome.